# How to move a searched value in a linked list of nodes to the head of the linked list?

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I am trying to write a `find(Object x)` method in which if a node storing an `Object y.equals(x)` is found, move that node to the front of the linked list (self-organizing list). If found, the method returns the value of the node that was moved to the front. If not found, return null.

My node inner-class contains a `Node<T> next` and an `Object val`.

Here is what I have tried:

```
public Object find(Object x) {

        //cant find an object that doesnt exist
        if (isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }

        // store the head
        Node tmp = head;
        //keep track of previous for updating the link if found
        Node prev = null;


        //traverse linked list
        while (tmp!=null) {
            //find x
            if (tmp.val.equals(x)) {
                //update node storing x to be the head
                tmp = head;

                //re-link the LL
                prev.next = tmp.next;

                return head.val;
            }
            //continue traversing if not found
            prev = tmp;
            tmp = tmp.next;
        }
        //x was not found, return null;
      return null;
    } // end find
```

My method is not finding objects properly, but at the moment I can't seem to find what is wrong with the code. Do I need to traverse the linked list in reverse order to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `if` block is not correctly rewiring your list. `tmp = head` will not move a node to become the head. You *lose* whatever `tmp` was referencing. You should *mutate* `tmp` (not assign to it) and indicate that its *successor* will be the current `head`. And then you should promote it as `head`:

```
    if (tmp.val.equals(x)) {
        // Only change something when the match is not the current head
        if (prev != null) { 
            // First(!) re-link the LL
            prev.next = tmp.next;
            // Move the node before the current head
            tmp.next = head;
            // Finally, make it the head
            head = temp;
        }
        return head.val;
    }
```